# Getting undefined value when I access value of an object

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Inside loginUser function, I want to access the value of accessToken which is in side the 'stsTokenManager' but when i try to access this value then i am getting 'undefind' value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
StyleSheet,
Text, 
View,
Image,
Button,
TouchableWithoutFeedback, StatusBar, TextInput,
SafeAreaView, Keyboard, TouchableOpacity,
KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox, Item, Label, Input } from 'native-base';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseconfig={
apiKey: " ",
authDomain: " ",
databaseURL: " ",
projectId: " ",
storageBucket: " ",
messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseconfig);

export default class Login extends Component{
// static navigationOptions = {
//     header: null
// }

componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user != null) {
        console.log(user)
      }
    })
}
loginUser = (email, password) => {         
    try {        
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password )
      .then((response)=>{
        //here i want to access values of 'stsTokenManager'
        console.log(response.user.stsTokenManager);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
      alert('Check your email or password')
    }
}
```

Please check my loginUser function because i am able to access email and other think but when i try to access stsTokenManager then i am getting undefind value.And, I am using firebase authentication.

Comment: Can you log to check what is `response.user`?

Comment: Yes, it is return the response.

Comment: So you mean `response.user` doesn't have key `stsTokenManager` ?

Comment: No,  `response.user`  have a key  `stsTokenManager`  but not access.

Comment: Can you update the question with `response` value you are getting? Seems like you may have to parse before accessing the keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`response.user` doesn't have an `stsTokenManager` property.

As a matter of fact, according to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword) `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` returns a `firebase.Promise` containing a non-null `firebase.auth.UserCredential`.

In turn, the `UserCredential` contains a `firebase.User` (that you get through `response.user` as you did) which does not have such a `stsTokenManager` property, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User

Answer (score 8):

`response.user.toJSON().stsTokenManager` works.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It answers the original question for anyone who has logged the authentication output and been unable to reconcile what they see there with what `user.stsTokenManager` resolves to.

Answer (score 1):

Do not depend on internal undocumented properties that are subject to change. Instead use public and official APIs that are already available. In your case, you can use `response.user.getIdToken()` to get the user's ID token, this also ensures the token you get is fresh if the cached one is expired.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.user)).stsTokenManager
```

or

```
response.user.toJSON().stsTokenManager
```